# @android:style/Theme_Holo resource not found

Tags: android

Being in Eclipse editing the `AndroidManifest.xml` the compiler shows me suggestion to add `@android:style/Theme_Holo`. But when compiling I get the message:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme_Holo')
```

Is there something wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Introduced in Honeycomb.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

Answer (score 5):

The holographic theme is new in Honeycomb (SDK level 11). If your project level is set below that, the theme won't be found. (Also note that the graphical layout editor can be set to a higher level than your project setting.)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error message showing up in the `res/values-v11` and `res/values-v14` folders of my Android project.

**Solved it** by setting the AndroidManifest.xml `android:targetSdkVersion` higher until it matched a version where the theme was available.

Example:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Works fine for:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

Also might have to modify the `target=<android:sdk-version>` line within the `project.properties` text file.